# Add comments in html to Tableau dashboard when exporting to HTML

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have a tableau dashboard that has a web object in it. The web object has comments made to that particular dashboard, it is basically just html in a server. When I open it in Tableau server, it works perfectly and it is displayed correctly. When I export it to PDF, the web object is not displaying at all. As per tableau docs, the web object will not be displayed. Is there another way of getting the web object or the html to display in the PDF?

I can use python and tabcmd to achieve this, I'm open to suggestions of any kind, this requirement is completely necessary for what I'm doing and I'm tearing my hear out at this point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Tableau Community Forums](https://community.tableau.com/message/237303#237303), it's not possible to export the contents of a web object inside a dashboard because of how the web object works:

> Thank you for contacting Tableau Technical Support. I understand
>   exported PDF on Tableau Server is not including the contents of web
>   pages. Please let me know if I misunderstood your request.
>
> It is the expected behavior that exporting views to PDF will not
>   include web page objects. The dashboard containing a web page object
>   has no knowledge of what is in the web browser object so it is left
>   blank.

One way I could think to do this is build a web data connector to pull the comments as text data, then do some string manipulation to make a view formatted how you want, and add that view to your dashboard.

Comment: After fighting with this for a while, yeah, it is not possible. What I ended up doing was to remove the web object and creating a python script to convert the HTML to a separate PDF and then join all the PDFs, I think this is kind of crappy this is not possible. :)